# StaffHub Powershell Cmdlet - Team ID Must Have Team_guid pattern

Tags: powershell, office365

I am getting the following error message when trying to use the Get-StaffHubMember cmd in PowerShell.

> {"error":{"code":"BadRequest","message":"The request has invalid
>   fields","details":[{"code":"BadRequest","message":"Team  ID must have
>   TEAM_guid pattern (GUIDs in lower case).","target":"teamId"}]}}
>
> RequestId: 9217076c-5569-4a78-b443-ba2212a737da Get-StaffHubMember :
>   Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest' At line:1
>   char:1
>
> - Get-StaffHubMember
> - ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-StaffHubMember], HttpOperationException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : 1001,Microsoft.OutlookApps.StaffHub.PowershellCmdlets.Commands.GetStaffHubMember

I have tried using the Team Name, and the GUID from the URL
/app/TEAM_ad49352bd16580f09ea33abad222b99d/schedules

trying every combination of

- Team Name
- TEAM_ad49352bd16580f09ea33abad222b99d
- ad49352bd16580f09ea33abad222b99d
- "TEAM_ad49352bd16580f09ea33abad222b99d"
- "ad49352bd16580f09ea33abad222b99d"
- "Team Name"

However, I keep on getting the same error. How do I find the right GUID to use?

Answer (score 0):

Taking the GUID from the URL is correct. However, the GUID needs to be formatted with the dashes in the 8-4-4-4-12 pattern.

Thus the proper parameter to pass is:

TEAM_ad49352b-d165-80f0-9ea3-3abad222b99d

Comment: If pass TeamID, will this "Remove-StaffHubMember" command also error? Also, I noticed that the "Get-StaffHubMember" cmdlet is currently in Beta. Here is link :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/staffhub/get-staffhubmember?view=staffhub-ps

Comment: @SimonLi It says in Beta, but it really looks like everything is in Alpha. You shouldn't get an error if you pass a correctly formatted TeamID.